# Sorting a List<object> filled with anonymous types without LINQ

Tags: c#, list, sorting, lambda

```
Random r = new Random();
List<object> myList = new List<object>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  myList.Add(new { A = r.Next(), B = r.Next() });

myList.Sort( (obj1, obj2) => obj1.A.CompareTo(obj2.A) );
```

The above code defines a generic `List` an populates it with 100 anonymous variables with two members, A and B.

Let's say I want to sort myList on A. The final line attempts to sort the list, however this code clearly doesn't compile because the compiler doesn't know what the list of objects contains.

Without using LINQ, is it possible to somehow sort this list using a lambda or similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to sort it without LINQ, as long as you manage to declare your list as that of a List of objects of anonymous type using the `var` syntax, or are willing to use `dynamic`:

```
Random r = new Random();
List<dynamic> myList = new List<object>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    myList.Add(new { A = r.Next(), B = r.Next() });

myList.Sort( (obj1, obj2) => obj1.A.CompareTo(obj2.A) );
```

Comment: @Jason I re-read the answer, and realized that the first part might be confusing, so I mentioned `var`.

Comment: +1. To use strongly typed version see my answer (requires helper method to my knowledge)

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use LINQ if you use implicit typing very carefully:

```
var myList = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                       .Select(index => new { A = r.Next(), B = r.Next() })
                       .ToList();
myList.Sort( (obj1, obj2) => obj1.A.CompareTo(obj2.A) );
```

Second, if you're willing to use `dynamic`, type the list as a `List<dynamic>` and then you can use LINQ directly.

However, I really don't see why you insist on being glued to anonymous types. Just make a nominal type and bask in the glory that is strong-typing, compile-time safety, and LINQ!

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic in LINQ - you can look at all method signatures and see how types get figured out.

You want something like this to create list of your type (similar of `ToList()` extension):

```
List<T> NewList<T>(T ignored)
{
    return new List<T>();
}
```

and use it as

```
Random r = new Random();
var myList = NewList(new { A = r.Next(), B = r.Next() });

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  myList.Add(new { A = r.Next(), B = r.Next() });

myList.Sort( (obj1, obj2) => obj1.A.CompareTo(obj2.A) );
```