# How to sort upon <TEntity> unknown dynamic generic List?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, generics

**Upadate:**

I have prepared a generic function for capturing database rows for generation the listing. My method is exactly like this.

```
    public class GenericDataAccess<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal ELearningDBContext ELearningDBContext;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> ELearningDBSet;

        public GenericDataAccess(ELearningDBContext context)
        {
            this.ELearningDBContext = context;
            this.ELearningDBSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
        public virtual PagingModel<TEntity> GetAllPaged(int pagesize, NameValueCollection queryString)
        {
            return ELearningDBSet.AsQueryable().ToList();
        }
     }
```

Here I am facing a problem to sort this list. Because the `TEntity` is changing time to time. However, I have a common field in every `Entity` named `Id`. So I want to sort each and every model by `Id` in `descending` order.

I have tried this way. But it was not effective, moreover, it's generating an exception.

```
ELearningDBSet.AsQueryable()..OrderByDescending(i=>typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("Id")).ToList();
```

I have gone through these questions [Q1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/557fd42d-908a-489b-ad4f-b889870a5f27/dynamic-order-by-for-list-of-custom-objects?forum=csharplanguage), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234431/sorting-a-generic-list-by-an-external-sort-order), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694654/sorting-a-listobject-filled-with-anonymous-types-without-linq), [Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053003/c-sharp-dynamic-generic-list). However, these were not effective. I prefer `C#` code. Any kind of perfect solution is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it's the table context. For example `internal DbSet<TEntity> ELearningDBSet;`

Comment: Do all the `Entity`s derive from the same `Entity` class?

Comment: Could you please see that, if it's not enough then please ask.

Comment: Please see my question in the previous comment. Also what exception do you get?

Comment: `Do all the Entitys derive from the same Entity class?` => No. `Also what exception do you get?` => I just want to sort them `descending`  order by `Id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow!! I have just got a wonderful solution. I have just used it.

```
 ELearningDBSet.AsQueryable().SortBy("Id" + " Desc").ToList();
```

Here the `SortBy()` function I used, got it from the .Net Library named `System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryExtensions`.  For more details see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.queryextensions(v=vs.110).aspx). Really it was a wonderful and outstanding solution for me.

Comment: This is not user defined function. I have got the function from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryExtensions`

Comment: I got it and i'm doing that. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Using a presentation layer library to a repository class is at best a "hack", secondly you open yourself up to run time issues since you could encounter a `TEntity` object that doesn't have the required `Id` property.

Answer (score 2):

Create an interface for all of your data entities to implement

```
public interface IEntityBase
{
    long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your data class, in your case `TEntity`, Implement the `IEntityBase` interface.

```
public partial class MyTEntity: IEntityBase
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    //Other attributes as needed.
}
```

In your generic class `GenericDataAccess<TEntity>` add a constraint to make TEntity implement the new interface `IEntityBase`. Then in the `GetAllPaged` method add the `OrderByDescending()` method call using the IEntityBase.Id property.

```
public class GenericDataAccess<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntityBase
    {
        internal ELearningDBContext ELearningDBContext;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> ELearningDBSet;

        public GenericDataAccess(ELearningDBContext context)
        {
            this.ELearningDBContext = context;
            this.ELearningDBSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
        public virtual PagingModel<TEntity> GetAllPaged(int pagesize, NameValueCollection queryString)
        {
            return ELearningDBSet.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).ToList();
        }
     }
```

**UPDATED:** Added the `partial` descriptor for the `MyEntity`class.

Comment: You should be using partial classes for maintainability

Comment: @Mafii are you referring to the `MyEntity` class specifically?

Comment: Yes. Create a new file, make the class partial, and add the interface (and if required the implementation with an alias). When using EF6, the entity itself should be partial by default

Answer (score 1):

You can build an `Expression tree` yourself  e.g.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string field)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var exp = Expression.Property(p, field);
    return source.OrderBy(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(exp, p));
}
```